# Integrate AD with RHEL

Tags: linux, powershell, active-directory, redhat-enterprise-linux, remote

Is there any way that RHEL can be integrated with the Active Directory.
Currently running the below from the Powershell ISE with RemoteAdmin Tools installed on windows.

```
Get-ADUser -Server AD.com -Filter '*' -Properties '*'
```

I know RHEL supports PowerShell but how to integrate the Linux with the Active Directory to pull the user's list of that AD Domain.

Comment: You want to know if you can run that same command on a RHEL server and get the same results?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to run the same command from a Linux. Trying to figure out how to integrate the  Linux Machine with AD.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have this on staackoverflow as well, that I just responded to.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52900369/integrate-ad-with-rhel/52902111#52902111

Comment: This should be a comment.